# How to pass generic class objects with a different type to one List?

Tags: c#, list, class, object, generics

Hello I need some inspiration,

I have a waypoint class like so:

```
public class Waypoint<T> {

}
```

and I would like to add all my waypoints to one list like so:

```
var w1 = new Waypoint<Item>();
var w2 = new Waypoint<Player>();
var waypoints = new List<Waypoint<?>>();
```

Problem is, they are not all of the same Type.
Is there a way that I can add different types to one list?

Anybody know an easy workaround?
Language: C#

Kind regards,

Venomous

Comment: what language is this? I assumed C++ and wrote an answer before I noticed that your code isnt C++....

Comment: yes my bad, it's C#

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to archive? It seems you are not using the right tool for the job.

Comment: class<T> is **not valid** C# code

Comment: Bad wording, but you get the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a generic base class, you could define Waypoint as an interface and have Item and Player implement it. That way you can have a list of IWaypoints like you want.

```
interface IWaypoint
{
    Point GetPosition();//whatever a waypoint should do
}

class Item : IWaypoint
{
    Point location;
    public Point GetPosition()
    {
       return location;
    }
}

class Player : IWaypoint
{
    Point position;
    float movespeed;
    public Point GetPosition()
    {
        return position * movespeed;
    }
}

void main()
{
    List<IWaypoint> waypoints = new List<IWaypoint>();
    waypoints.Add(new Player());
    waypoints.Add(new Item());
    foreach (IWaypoint wp in waypoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wp.GetPosition());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also do something similar with a generic base class `Waypoint<T> : IWaypoint`.  That provides a common base class for `Waypoint<Player>` and `WayPoint<Item>` but doesn't require modification of `Player` or `Item`.

Comment: @BJMyers Good idea too. I kinda just assumed it was a waypoint like you'd see on Skyrim's map.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I will use this. I can probably work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help, but you could do something like this:

```
struct AbstractWayPoint {};

template<typename T> 
struct WayPoint : AbstractWayPoint {};

std::list<AbstractWayPoint*> theList;
```

Of course this only makes sense, if the interface of whatever you want to do with that waypoints in the list does not depend on the template parameter. However, this isnt such a huge restriction as it may seem at first glance, eg one can do something like this:

```
struct AbstractWayPoint {
    virtual void doSomething(double x) = 0;
};

template<typename T> 
struct WayPoint : AbstractWayPoint {
    virtual void doSomething(double x) {
        T t;
        t.someMethod(x);
    }
};
```

PS: when I wrote this answer, I thought the question is about C++. I know only little C#, so unless someone will point out that something like this cannot be done in C# I will just leave the answer. Anyhow OP was asking for "some inspiration" ;)

PPS: ...btw if your waypoints dont share a common interface, imho it is questionable whether it makes sense to put them into a list in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are coding in C#, there is no common base class for `Waypoint<Item>` and `Waypoint<Player>` except for `object` so the type of collection would be `List<object>` (or even `ArrayList`).

Even if `Item` and `Player` both derived from the same base class, you wouldn't be able to define a `List<Waypoint<Base>>` and add both `Waypoint<Item>` and `Waypoint<Player>` objects to this list.

`Waypoint<Item>` is not a derived type of `Waypoint<Base>` just because `Item` is a derived type of `Base`.

Comment: Is there no way around this?
I'm using delegates to define some configuration that you can pass to each type into the waypoint, and it would be stupid to create a list for each type to store the waypoints.

Comment: There is no way to ignore the type-safety in the programming language if that's what you are asking. You can store all objects in the same List<object> as I mentioned in my answer though. But - as also mentioned - there is no other common base class between your generic types.

Comment: `Waypoint<object>` is the first thing that I tried but cannot seem to convert the objects,
how can I cast `Waypoint<T>` to an object?
I've tried: `(Waypoint<object>)Convert.ChangeType(waypoint, typeof(Waypoint<object>));` But doesn't work, say's I need to implement `IConvertible`

Comment: Why do you need Waypoint<object>. It should be List<object>, not List<Waypoint<object>>. Please read my answer again. There is no relationsshp between a Waypoint<Item> and a Waypoint<object>. Waypoint<Item> only derives from object. Not Waypoint<object>.

Comment: Okay I understand, but if I use List<object> I will have no way to know which object is item for  example or player

Comment: Yes. But that's another story :) The answer to your original question is that there is no common base type for your generic types. You *could* define a common base type and create a List<Base> or use a List<object>.